# WSO2 API Manager response "no response from server" when send Parameters with '*'

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

when I use the sample PizzaShackAPI /order/{orderid} ,
if the parameters with character "*",
it Response "no response from server" as the same as my api;
How can this be fixed?

[image: Pic Send]
[image: Pic Response]

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a [reserved character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), you must escape it as `%2A` because you aren't using it for the reserved purpose.

Comment: 3Q,but I can use it in real api server and wso2 api manager can not;does that mean all my api clients need to translate it before send request to wso2 api manager? --sorry for my poor english;